# label column values with currency, except cells which are string

Tags: python, pandas

i am looking for a solution to append a currency to floats. but my dataframe column also includes a string/empty cell. i expect a solution that only appends the currency to the floats in the column.

```
nr = [100, 200, 300, '' ,500]
text = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(nr, text)),columns=['Nr', 'Text'])
```

i tried:

```
df['Nr'] = df['Nr'].astype(float).map("{:,.2f} €".format) #does not work
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df['Nr'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Nr']).map(lambda val: '' if np.isnan(val) else f'{val:,.2f} €')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas.to_numeric) with `errors="coerce"`. This will convert all non-numeric values to `NaN`. Then use `.notna()` for boolean indexing:

```
m = pd.to_numeric(df.Nr, errors="coerce").notna()
df.loc[m, "Nr"] = df.loc[m, "Nr"].apply("{:,.2f} €".format)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Nr Text
0  100.00 €    a
1  200.00 €    b
2  300.00 €    c
3              d
4  500.00 €    e
```